Arrow outside polar plot matplotlib
I am trying to add an arrow pointing to the outside of a polar plot. I need it to indicate an aircraft heading. It needs to be outside the plot area and ideally attached to the plot edge pointing toward the center. It would look like this
Polar plot with arrow outside
I have only been able to get the arrow within the plotted area and have not seen anything in the documentation that would achieve what I am looking to do.

One of the options is to annotate :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})
r, theta = ax.get_rmax(), np.deg2rad(45)

ax.annotate(
    "",
    xy=(theta, r),
    xytext=(theta, r + 0.5), # < arrow's length
    arrowprops=dict(fc="C0", width=10, headwidth=25),
)

ax.grid(False)
ax.spines["polar"].set_lw(2)
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])

plt.show()


